# ServiceStack Different Security based on routes

Tags: servicestack

We have a ServiceStack host, in which we have modularised the services.  In addition we have a custom authentication solution based on the Basic Authentication. But what we would like to do is have different authentication methods for different services, maybe based on routes?  Is this possible?

Secondly, is it possible to assign a common route prefix based on the service?  As I said we have modularised our services, and in the AppHost definition we enter the assemblies of the different services, but is it possible to change the route prefix, i.e. Service1 to localhost/api1/servicemethods, Service2 to localhost/api2/servicemethods etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit that a Service should only authenticate with a specific provider by specifying the provider name in the `[Authenticate]` attribute, e.g:

```cs
[Authenticate(AuthenticateService.ApiKeyProvider)]
public class ApiKeyAuthServices : Service
{
    public object Any(ApiKeyOnly request) => ...;
}

[Authenticate(AuthenticateService.JwtProvider)]
public class JwtAuthServices : Service
{
    public object Any(JwtOnly request) => ...;
}
```

Otherwise inside your Service you can inspect how the request was authenticated by looking at `base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>().AuthProvider`.

For defining dynamic routes have a look at:

- [Auto Route Generation Strategies](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies)
- [Dynamically adding Route Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes)
- [Customizing Defined Routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#customizing-defined-routes)

Although ServiceStack isn't designed to define different sets of Apps within the same AppHost so if that's what you're trying to do I'd recommend instead having different AppHosts and using the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) for any Service-to-Service communication.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  This looks exactly what I need, however I am having a few implementation issues that I am hoping you can help with.

Comment: I have two custom Auth providers, both are based on the BasicAuthProvider, but validate in different ways internally.

In AppHost I have registered both providers and that looks like it worked correctly.

Now I am trying to restrict on Service to use a specific auth provider.  In the [Authenticate] block I am using the Provider= and trying to enter a string name as it appears to want.

Comment: I tried to use the ProviderClass.Name property, but it is not happy with it being a static string not a const.

I tried to manually set the Name properties of the two auth providers to be different, but they overwrote each other.   So I create a value to override the Name property in the base class.  But still the authenticate is not happy.

I tried to enter a const string with the name I set in the AuthProviders constructor, it accepts this, but when I try to call a method, I receive the warning no auth provider with  that name found.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @MarkLFT Metadata attributes are embedded in .dll's so they can need to be compile-time constants, you could use `AuthenticateService.BasicProvider` or just the `"basic"` string literal. To help test you can use `AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders()` to resolve all registered providers and `AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders(provider)` to filter where `IAuthProvider.Provider == provider`

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your reply.  I must be doing something fundamentally wrong, even though I have registered two custom authproviders, both based on the BasicAuthProvider, using AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders() returns an empty array.

This is the code I use to register the AuthProviders, and they both allow me to login, so I know they are working.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new RMCredentialsAuthProvider(),
                    new RMKOTAuthProvider()
                }));
```

The code from one of the custom providers is

```
public class RMKOTAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    #region Public Constructors

    public RMKOTAuthProvider() : base()
    {
        
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Methods

    public override Task<IHttpResult> OnAuthenticatedAsync(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        session.FirstName = session.UserAuthName;
        session.Roles = new List<string>
        {
            "KOT"
        };

        authService.SaveSessionAsync(session, SessionExpiry);

        return base.OnAuthenticatedAsync(authService, session, tokens, authInfo, token);
    }

    public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userName.IsNullOrEmpty() || password.IsNullOrEmpty())
                return Task.FromResult(false);

            var result = VerifyUser(username, password);

            return Task.FromResult(result);
            
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

Can you please explain what step I am missing such that GetAuthProviders() can list the providers, and I can use the metadata you described earlier.

Many thanks in advance for your help with this.

Comment: I have found how to get the providers using GetProviders(), I needed to rearrange the order in the AppHost.Configure method. 

But now I have a strange thing, in the swagger-ui, I use the OpenAPI plugin. when I click on authorise it is asking for an API Key not a username and password.   Both of our AuthProviders are based on the Basic Provider, so it should be requesting a password.  We have no ApiKey providers or settings anywhere in the API.  Is this a bug in the OpenAPI plugin because we are using custom providers, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In addition to swagger not using the correct authentication type, when using the JsonServiceClient and SetCredentials method, I receive an error message    "No configuration was added for OAuth provider 'basic'".  It seems if using custom auth providers, and we change the provider value to use in the Authenticate metadata, then it no longer knows how to manage the login process.

Comment: Note you should update your question not add a new question as an answer. In regards to this you shouldn't have more than 1 AuthProvider sharing the same provider name or implementing the same auth provider, like HTTP Basic Auth which is going to be in conflict trying to authenticate the same HTTP Basic Auth request.  To specify a unique name call the base (IAppSettings, realm, provider) constructor or if you only have 1 you can use the default `basic` provider name and `/auth/basic` realm in the default constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was all related, that is why I added it to this conversation.

I have solved my initial problem by creating only a single custom provider, then in it using the Request.Dto to find the destination, and applying the correct authentication checking.  It seems very messy but it works.

Can I suggest a change, so the metadata can use the Name property in place of the Provider, maybe then we could use multiple providers with the same base type.  This would allow cleaner code.   I don't know if would be helpful for others also?

Comment: You've added a question as an answer which will eventually get deleted whenever a mod sees it, you'd need to have either update your existing question or ask a new one. Not sure what `Name` property that you're referring to, the only `Name` property on `BasicAuthProvider` is static so it can't be used directly, but it is used as the default value for its `Provider` name.